# Splitting rmcorr into three variables in R

Tags: r, split, output

I am attempting to run repeated-measures correlations using function 'rmcorr', but am struggling to find a way to 'split' the results in terms of an additional variable. In SPSS, one can use the split file function to do this. I have already tried 'split' functions but it doesnt seem to work with rmcorr. Just to clarify, I would like to run a rmcorr correlation between x and y but have the output shown for each category of another variable (e.g. school (1) Private, (2) State, (3)Military. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Hi Kaaren. We really need to see some example code and data to get a concrete idea of what you mean. Describing your problem in words is useful, but without a motivating example, it just leaves too many ambiguities for potential answerers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `rmcorr` does not have this capability, but it is possible to build a wrapper around the function to achieve this:

```r
library(rmcorr)

rmcorrdf <- function(participant, measure1, measure2, dataset, group) {
  df_splits <- split(dataset, dataset[[deparse(substitute(group))]])
  dfs <- lapply(df_splits, function(d) {
  mod <- eval(call("rmcorr", substitute(participant, parent.frame(2)), 
              substitute(measure1, parent.frame(2)), 
              substitute(measure2, parent.frame(2)), 
              d))
  data.frame(r = mod$r, DOF = mod$df, p = mod$p, 
             CI.lower = mod$CI[1], CI.upper = mod$CI[2])})
  result <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
  result$Group <- names(dfs)
  `rownames<-`(result, seq(nrow(result)))[c(6, 1:5)]
}
```

So if we have data like this:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(subject = rep(LETTERS, each = 4),
                 y1 = rnorm(104), y2 = rnorm(104, 11),
                 group = sample(c("Private", "State", "Military"), 104, TRUE))
head(df)
#>   subject         y1       y2    group
#> 1       A -0.6264538 10.34542    State
#> 2       A  0.1836433 12.76729  Private
#> 3       A -0.8356286 11.71671  Private
#> 4       A  1.5952808 11.91017 Military
#> 5       B  0.3295078 11.38419    State
#> 6       B -0.8204684 12.68218    State
```

Then we can do:

```
rmcorrdf(subject, y1, y2, df, group)
#>      Group          r DOF         p   CI.lower  CI.upper
#> 1 Military  0.2033325  14 0.4500700 -0.3668212 0.6624448
#> 2  Private -0.0856067  17 0.7274957 -0.5438730 0.4119900
#> 3    State  0.3003098  10 0.3429159 -0.4061038 0.7820616
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your willingness to help, it's greatly appreciated! Unfortunately, the code doesn't seem to work for me, it keeps returning the + sign and won't compute the commands and tells me that my y and x objects cannot be found. But I think this is more the issue with my coding than yours. Will play around with it tomorrow in the hopes that it works - thanks!